# Building dynamc queries in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have been struggling far too long on this one. I have a fairly complex query that I have pieced together, but it seems to me to be way too verbose and ugly.
I have an advanced tickets search form that has 8 different search fields, plus created_at and updated_at search options in which users can choose the day, month, and/or year to filter their results.
I am building query conditions in my tickets_controller like this.

```
conditions  = String.new
  arguments = []

  unless params[:id].blank?
    conditions << ' AND ' unless conditions.length == 0
    conditions << 'tickets.id = ?'
    arguments << params[:id]
  end

  unless params[:organization].blank?
    conditions << ' AND ' unless conditions.length == 0
    conditions << 'organizations.name ILIKE ?'
    arguments << "%#{params[:organization]}%" 
  end

  unless params[:keywords].blank?
    conditions << ' AND ' unless conditions.length == 0
    conditions << 'subject ILIKE ?'
    arguments << "%#{params[:keywords]}%"
  end

  unless params[:status_id].blank?
    conditions << ' AND ' unless conditions.length == 0
    conditions << 'status_id = ?'
    arguments << params[:status_id]
  end

  unless params[:resolution_status_id].blank?
    conditions << ' AND ' unless conditions.length == 0
    conditions << 'resolution_status_id = ?'
    arguments << params[:resolution_status_id]
  end

  unless params[:priority_id].blank?
    conditions << ' AND ' unless conditions.length == 0
    conditions << 'priority_id = ?'
    arguments << params[:priority_id]
  end

  unless params[:assigned_to_id].blank?
    conditions << ' AND ' unless conditions.length == 0
    conditions << 'assigned_to_id = ?'
    arguments << params[:assigned_to_id]
  end


  @tickets = Ticket.joins(:organization).where(conditions, arguments).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).order("updated_at DESC")
```

It gets confusing for me on fields that have special joins. For example, I have and email column on another table and have created a separate method in tickets.rb that looks like this.

```
def self.email(email)
    joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN assignments ON assignments.person_id = tickets.owner_id').where('assignments.email_address ILIKE ?', email)
end
```

then call it with a terinary like this

```
params[:email].blank? ? nil : @tickets = @tickets.email("%#{params[:email]}%")
```

I also have a contact search field that searches both the first name, and last name of my people table. I created a seperate method that looks like this...

```
def self.contact(contact)  
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON people.user_id = tickets.owner_id').where('people.last ILIKE ? OR people.first ILIKE ?', contact, contact)
end
```

Then call it in another terinary as I did with the params[:email].
This really doesn't seem like the best way to go about it to me, but I am new to programming and haven't been able to come up with anything more elegant. I have a number or these terniary operators that are building up my query, and while it is working just fine, I can't help but feel like I'm doing something wrong here.
I hope this is enough information to go on, if not I can clarify when needed.

Comment: is it a rails-3 specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are doing manually all of `ActiveRecord`'s job.

I would have a scope for each of your cases:

eg:

```
#class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

scope :with_subject lambda { |keyword| where('subject ILIKE ?', keyword) }
scope :with_status_id { |s_id| where(status_id: s_id) }
```

which will be used as follows:

```
@tickets = Ticket.scoped
@tickets = @tickets.with_subject(params[:keywords]) unless params[:keywords].blank?
@tickets = @tickets.with_status_id(params[:status_id]) if params[:status_id].present?
```

the joins can be also chained in AR syntax

```
@tickets = @tickets.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN people ON people.user_id = tickets.owner_id')
```

The only problem is the use of `OR` clauses, which IMO are more readable in the SQL syntax

```
where('people.last ILIKE ? OR people.first ILIKE ?', contact, contact)
```

Hope it helps.

PS: You can find more on the subject on the relevant [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)